# Why does my sesson close?

Tags: hibernate

I am attempting to update a table in my hibernate session and then refresh my local data table by refetching the hibernate table.  If I do not do the update, I can refresh the local data table with no problem, but when I add the update, I get the following error in the server log:

SEVERE: org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!

Can anyone give me a suggestion on what I am doing wrong and what I can do to fix the problem?

Thanks.

Here is the code to do the update.  It seems to work correctly, since I do not get any of the exceptions and I get a return stat value of 1 to indicate the table was updated and committed.

```
public int updatePolygonGroupAtrributes( long id, String groupName, String color, long ownerId, int updtUserId )
{
    int stat = 0;
    TbPolygonGroup polyGroup = null;
    TbCustAccount custAcct = null;
    TbUser user = null;

    try
    {
        org.hibernate.Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        polyGroup = (TbPolygonGroup)session.get(TbPolygonGroup.class, id);
        polyGroup.setVcPolygonGroup(groupName);
        polyGroup.setVcColor(color);
        custAcct = (TbCustAccount)session.get(TbCustAccount.class, ownerId);
        System.out.println( "<DbHelper.updatePolygonGroupAtrributes> ownerId = "+custAcct.getBiAccountId()+", Name = "+custAcct.getVcCustAccountName() );
        polyGroup.setTbCustAccount(custAcct);
        polyGroup.setDtUpdTime( new Date() );
        user = (TbUser)session.get(TbUser.class, updtUserId);
        System.out.println( "<DbHelper.updatePolygonGroupAtrributes> update User Id = "+user.getIuserId()+", Name = "+user.getVcUserFirstName()+" "+user.getVcUserLastName() );
        polyGroup.setTbUser(user);
        try
        {
            session.update(polyGroup);
            tx.commit();
            stat = 1;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
            status = e.getMessage();
            stat = -1;
        }
    }
    catch( Exception ex )
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        status = ex.getMessage();
        stat = -1;
    }
    return stat;
}
```

Here is the code where I call the update in my applicaton (not really relevant except to show the flow of what I am doing).

```
public void polyGroupUpdateAction()
{
    int changed = 0;
    String clr = "#"+polyColor;
    long ownId = sb1.getLong( selectedPolyOwner, 0 );
    long groupId = selectedPolygonGroup.getBiPolygonGroupId();
    int updUserId = sb1.getLoginUserId();
    int retVal = dbHelper.updatePolygonGroupAtrributes(groupId, polyName, clr, ownId, updUserId);
    if( retVal < 0 )
    {
        sb1.setMessage( "Error updating Polygon Group: "+dbHelper.getStatus() );
        return;
    }
    System.out.println("---------<DeviceSessionBean.polyGroupUpdateAction> Return value = "+retVal);
    sb1.setMessage("Polygon Group has been updated.");
    fillPolyGroupList();
    return;
}
```

Here is the relevant code where I refill my local tables (shows where the error occurs)

```
public void fillPolyGroupList()
{
    System.out.println( "<DeviceSessionBean.fillPolyGroupList> Entering ... ");
    tbPolygonGroupList = dbHelper.getPolygonGroup();
    System.out.println( "<DeviceSessionBean.fillPolyGroupList> After reloading polygon group list ... ");
    polygonGroupDataModel = new PolygonGroupDataModel(tbPolygonGroupList);
}
```

Here is the session log that shows the update returns successfully, but gives the error when I attempt to re-read the data table in fillPolyGroupList();

```
INFO: <DbHelper.updatePolygonGroupAtrributes> ownerId = 74, Name = TransCore - David Kerr
INFO: <DbHelper.updatePolygonGroupAtrributes> update User Id = 2, Name = Transcore System
INFO: ---------<DeviceSessionBean.polyGroupUpdateAction> Return value = 1
INFO: <DeviceSessionBean.fillPolyGroupList> Entering ... 
SEVERE: org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!
at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.errorIfClosed(AbstractSessionImpl.java:49)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1319)
.....
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

INFO: <DeviceSessionBean.fillPolyGroupList> After reloading polygon group list ... 
WARNING: #{deviceSessionBean.polyGroupUpdateAction}: java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.faces.FacesException: #{deviceSessionBean.polyGroupUpdateAction}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
....
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried the suggested solution and changed the mode to "manual" rather than "thread" and doing an openSession() and closeSession() around each of my 96 methods that access hibernate.  That did not work. After a couple of calls to the access methods, I got "no session" errors.  So that solution did not work for some reason, not to mention that it added a lot of un-necessary overhead, since only 3 of the 96 methods actually did updates.

So, rather than wrap all the methods with the open/close session code, I found that I get the proper result by just re-opening a session after the commit().

In the code above I have the line:

```
tx.commit();
```

I found that if I just add an openSession() after this, I get the results I was looking for.  So the above code has changed from the tx.commit() above to:

```
tx.commit();
this.session - HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
```

I only need to add this to the 3 (at this time) methods that actually do updates and the other 93 (at this time) methods can remain as written without having to

Answer (score 0):

> When you commit the transaction in the session Hibernate will
>   automatically close the session meaning it can’t be reused.

http://www.17od.com/2006/11/06/using-managed-sessions-in-hibernate-to-ease-unit-testing/

---

On my link it also explains how to control your session manually so test it on a function and then modify all :)

---

If you are new to hibernate, you'd better try to start your project from a maven archetype which will provide you a decent project structure with an already configured hibernate/spring for exemple.

Install maven, type mvn archetype:generate, select the technos you want to use. Then type mvn eclipse:eclipse to generate the eclipse config files on your new project and finally import it to eclipse.
It will help you to get started by setting you a full stack. (Ex archetype appfuse-basic-spring will create a app with SpringMVC, Spring and Hibernate)

Comment: Btw wtf is dbHelper? We have dao's nowadays

Comment: I'm new to hibernate and I saw this in a hibernate tutorial for netbeans.  I also saw the page you referred to and was hoping to not have to rewrite all the 50+ functions that I have for fetching data that do no updates.